# SQL query for displaying product sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have sales table which consists, ItemSize, GroupName, Quantity, ProductID, etc...

Now I want to display sales according to following format

```
GroupName   ItemSize  Quantity   ItemSize  Quantity
```

means

```
BEER    350ml   500    650ml   1000
```

How I can achieve this in SQL SERVER 2005 EXPRESS (T-SQL)? Thanks

UPDATED:

its my sales table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesLog](
[SalesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MemoNo] [int] NULL,
[ProductCode] [int] NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL,
[Price] [int] NULL,
[ProductGroup] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SalesLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SalesID] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

its my Product table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[pName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[pSize] [int] NULL,
[pPrice] [int] NULL,
[pPackQty] [int] NULL,
[pGroup] [int] NULL,
[pCode] [int] NULL,
[pStock] [int] NULL,
[pYrStock] [int] NULL,
[pClearStock] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
   [ProductId] ASC
   ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Your question needs to be clarified.  I think I know what you're asking, but I had to stare at it a long time.  What's the table definition?  Including a few rows of sample data would be a good idea as well.

Comment: I don't think you can use ItemSize and Quantity twice. You might need to have unique names so you can pivot the data

Comment: i have an foxpro based application which prints data in same format and store data in same way as i did.

Comment: Do you want only two columns of ItemSize/Quantity pairs, or do you want an ItemSize/Quantity column for each ItemSize (i.e. you have more than two item sizes for any given product)?

Comment: i want an ItemSize/Quantity column for each ItemSize (i.e. I have more than two item sizes for any given product).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could aggregate the data using SUM and CASE statements.

Using your table definitions (and some very minimal made up data), here is an example of how you could do it:

```
--** Create test tables
DECLARE @SalesLog TABLE ( 
SalesID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
MemoNo int NULL, 
ProductCode int NULL, 
Quantity int NULL, 
Price int NULL, 
ProductGroup int NULL)

DECLARE @Products TABLE( 
ProductId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
pName nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, 
pSize int NULL, 
pPrice int NULL, 
pPackQty int NULL, 
pGroup int NULL, 
pCode int NULL, 
pStock int NULL, 
pYrStock int NULL, 
pClearStock int NULL)

--** Setup test data
INSERT INTO @SalesLog ( MemoNo, ProductCode, Quantity, Price, ProductGroup)
SELECT   0, 1, 500, 0, 1 UNION
SELECT   0, 2, 700, 0, 1 UNION   
SELECT   0, 2, 333, 0, 1 UNION   
SELECT   0, 3, 200, 0, 2 UNION
SELECT   0, 4, 125, 0, 2 ;

INSERT INTO @Products (pName, pSize, pPrice, pPackQty, pGroup, pCode, pStock, pYrStock, pClearStock)
SELECT 'Beer', 350, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 UNION
SELECT 'Beer', 650, 1 , 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0 UNION
SELECT 'Beer', 1000, 1 , 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0 UNION
SELECT 'Wine', 750, 1 , 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0 UNION 
SELECT 'Wine', 1000, 1 , 1, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0 ;

--** Example query
SELECT t.pName AS 'Product'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.Col = 1 THEN t.pSize END) AS 'Item Size'
     , ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 1 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS 'Quantity'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.Col = 2 THEN t.pSize END) AS 'Item Size'
     , ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 2 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS 'Quantity'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.Col = 3 THEN t.pSize END) AS 'Item Size'
     , ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 3 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS 'Quantity'
FROM (
SELECT pName
     , pCode
     , pGroup
     , pSize
     , sl.Quantity
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY p.pGroup ORDER BY p.pSize) AS Col
  FROM @Products AS p
  LEFT JOIN @SalesLog AS sl
    ON p.pGroup = sl.ProductGroup
   AND p.pCode = sl.ProductCode
     ) AS t
 GROUP BY t.pGroup
     , t.pName
;
```

The query uses the DENSE_RANK function to group items of a size together and to order them in assending order of size and this is used to work out which column the data should be written to.

Although there is a PIVOT operator in SQL Server 2005 and above, it isn't very helpful when you have different column heading types (item size and quantity in this case).

You will have to decide on the maximum number of product sizes that you want to report on as this is hard coded into the query. So if the maximum number of product sizes is 3 then you code the query as shown above. If, however, one of your products has 4 different sizes, then you are going to add an additional Item Size and Quantity pair of columns for t.Col = 4 and so on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Output is exactly as i want but SQL-Server query editor throws error on using more than one values statements.

this query is working on data available in query statement, how can i use this to my existing data from database tables Products, SalesLog..

Thanks

Comment: I'm very sorry about the creation of the test data not being SQL Server 2005 compatible. I have edited so that it will now work for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: As for using the query with yout existing tables, replace the table variables with your database tables - so just replace @Products with Products and @SalesLog with SalesLog.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to do a PIVOT table, where the different item sizes are represented as different columns rather than rows.  Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: my data is spread over in 3 tables, will PIVOT be able to do that.