# DataSet TableAdapter throwing OVER SQL construct or statement not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2008, t-sql

I have a t-sql query written with [this sample help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127708/sql-query-for-displaying-product-sales).

```
SELECT  t.gName AS 'Product'
, isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 1 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS '180ml'
, isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 2 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS '375ml'
, isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 3 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS '500ml'
, isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 4 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS '1000ml'
, isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Col = 5 THEN t.Quantity END),0) AS '2000ml'
FROM (
SELECT p.pName
     , p.pCode
     , p.pGroup
     , p.pSize, i.gName, i.gCode
     , sl.Quantity, sl.BillDate
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY p.pGroup ORDER BY p.pSize) AS Col 
    FROM 
        ItemGroup AS i INNER JOIN 
                          Products AS p ON i.gCode = p.pGroup INNER JOIN 
                          SalesLog AS sl ON p.pGroup = sl.pGroup
       AND p.pCode = sl.ProductCode   
       ) AS t where t.BillDate=@BillDate and t.pGroup!=15 and t.pGroup!=16
     GROUP BY t.gName
    order by t.gName
```

Its working in Management Studio Query Editor but not in DataSet throwing error like **The OVER SQL construct or statement not supported.**

this is query needed for for Report (.rdlc). Please help

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put this SQL in to a Stored Procedure or a View.  You can then populate your DataSet from there.

Comment: Good answer! 7 years later and still helps me. I'm wondering why the over function causes troubles on the TableAdapter. Shouldnt the SQL be executed on the SQL Server? How does the querry itself affect the adapter? I thought the adapter would start working, when it gets the results from the database. But throwing this exception tells a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The ADAPTER isnt able to create the diagram for the script. Right click, goto Panes, disselect the Diagram... and that's it! it runs :)

Comment: Right click where? What panes?