# How to show DataColumns in Dataset DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have a query that I put into a dataset as a datatable.  The query runs great, however in the datatable it does not list anything in the Data Column, there for I cannot report it...  Any ideas why this is not working?  My Query is below.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT timeclock.dtTimeIn, timeclock.dtTimeOut, employees.sfirstname,
       RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY dtTimeIn) rk1, --earliest record gets 1
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC) rk2 --latest record gets 1

    FROM   TimeClock INNER JOIN
                         Employees ON TimeClock.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID
    WHERE (dtTimeIn > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate())-1, 0)) AND (dtTimeOut < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) AND 
      (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
) A
WHERE rk2=1
```

Current output when I run the query:

```
  dtTimeIn                    dtTimeOut       sfirstname    rk1      rk2
2/7/2013 2:36:00 PM 2/7/2013 7:52:33 PM        Brian        10        1
```

[image]

When Creating the Table adapter in the wizzard... I get an error message:

```
The Wizard detected the following problems when configuring the TableAdapter:
"OpenTime":

Details:
Generated SELECT statement.
The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported
To add these components to your dataset, click Finish.
```

I'm guessing it doesn't like the query... But i'm not sure how else to accomplish the query other than using the "OVER" function...

Comment: What do you mean it does not list anything in the DataColumn?

Comment: Can you show us your compiled code?

Comment: Well within the dataset you have a "datatable" and a "tableadapter".  Inside the tableadapter is usually the "Fill,GetData()" any parameters go inside the ().  For the datatable, it usually shows the "Data Columns" which usually correspond to the "Select" columns.  However, there are not any "Data Columns" it's just blank... therefore if I try to create a report with report viewer it does not show anything to report.

Comment: @Love2Learn I'm not sure what you mean.  There litterally isn't any code, because it won't create the .rdlc.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a SqlDataAdapter to populate a DataTable. I'd like to see the C# code (if you're doing it this way) to see how you're populating the DataTable. (C# = compiled code)

Comment: I'm in the design feature of the dataset... There aren't any DataColumns.  Therefor when I create the reporviewer controll, and add it, it doesn't come with any columns to add for output...

Comment: @Love2Learn See Image posted above.

Comment: Can you poat code the screenshot of the UML diagram doesn't help much

Comment: @Shmewnix, move that `SQL` to `Storedprocedure` and Use that to populate your `dataset`

Comment: I can't add a stored procedure, or a stored function.  The database is a synced database, and I have no say over the synced data.

Comment: There is a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138725/dataset-tableadapter-throwing-over-sql-construct-or-statement-not-supported

Comment: @Bulat This again, does not solve my problem because I do not have the ability to add a stored procedure to the database.  I need to handle it at the query level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the limitations of the `TableAdapter` wizard, you have to create the `DataTable` using code.

```
DataTable dataTable;

using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    sqlConn.Open();

    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    using (sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlConn.CreateCommand())
    {

        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = '
            SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT timeclock.dtTimeIn, timeclock.dtTimeOut, employees.sfirstname,
                    RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY dtTimeIn) rk1, --earliest record gets 1
                    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC) rk2 --latest record gets 1

                FROM TimeClock INNER JOIN
                    Employees ON TimeClock.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID
                WHERE (dtTimeIn > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate())-1, 0)) AND (dtTimeOut < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) AND (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
            ) A
            WHERE rk2=1';

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
```

After having your `dataTable` filled, simply assign it to the ReportViewer's `DataSource`

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource(dataTable.TableName, dataTable);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
```

Please note that a large part of these code snippets are untested.

Answer (score 6):

I think instead of using the drag-and-drop interface to create a tableAdapter, because your query contains the `OVER SQL` construct (like the error says,) you'll have to create your tableAdapter and fill your datatable in code.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a view from your query and then simply select from your view, this should hide the OVER SQL from the tableAdapter.