# How to find first time of day and last time of day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query that grabs the first person from a department who punched in first, and the person from a department that punched in last.  Essentially this shows me who opened a location, and closed a location.  Below is my query I am using the "OVER" function, however the over function does not work for a dataset in VB.net  Are there any other options to replace the over function with?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT timeclock.dtTimeIn, timeclock.dtTimeOut, employees.sfirstname,
       RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY dtTimeIn) rk1, --earliest record gets 1
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC) rk2 --latest record gets 1

    FROM   TimeClock INNER JOIN
                         Employees ON TimeClock.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID
    WHERE (dtTimeIn > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate())-1, 0)) AND (dtTimeOut < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) AND 
      (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
) A
WHERE rk2=1
```

Comment: If you put your code into a stored procedure, why will VB.Net care if you used `OVER()` to derive the results or not?

Comment: I can't do stored procedure...  It's a synced databse and i do not have access to the main sync database

Comment: Or a view . . . But are you sure it is not working?  Should the `where` clause be `where rk2 = 1 or rk1 = 1` ?

Comment: The query works.  It just does not work correctly in vb.net for reporting.

Comment: What version of VB.net "reporting" is not capable of passing a SQL statement on to SQL Server? Why does VB.net care what your SQL syntax looks like? It should just pass it over to SQL Server. And what does "not work correctly" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781694/how-to-show-datacolumns-in-dataset-datatable

Comment: Well, when you say, "Doctor, it hurts when I do x", I'd say you shouldn't be surprised when the doctor says "Don't do x." In other words, you are trying to work around some drag-and-drop interface that most of us would never use in the first place. Why use something that doesn't understand T-SQL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I thank you for the insult.  My understanding is the idea of stackoverflow is to get help, and share knowledge?  I'm looking for an answer to a question.  If you have a better way, well then perhaps providing insight on how to get to the final answer is great.  Some people are not as advanced as you... I would remind you that you were also in my place once upon a time... I'm sure you received some sort of help.  I'm not looking for the answer, but simply looking for a way to get to the answer... I don't know anything but Drag and drop... that being said i'm open to learning

Comment: Wow, easy, where did I insult you? I was simply suggesting that maybe using this drag and drop thing isn't the best idea, that's all. Sorry if you don't find that useful - there are certainly less efficient ways to get those results that will likely work with your drag-and-drop thing, but I would prefer to eliminate the limitations than work around them. YMMV. I hope you find a solution but don't be so defensive - you won't get a lot of value out of this site if you freak out over all constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT  tc.dtTimeIn
        , tc.dtTimeOut
        , e.sfirstname
FROM    TimeClock tc
JOIN    Employees e ON tc.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
JOIN    (               
            SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, tc.dtTimeIn), 0) _date
                    , MIN(tc.dtTimeIn) dtTimeIn
                    , MAX(tc.dtTimeOut) dtTimeOut
            FROM    TimeClock tc
            WHERE   e.sDept IN ('1', '2', '3')
            GROUP BY
                    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, tc.dtTimeIn), 0)
) t ON  t._date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AND     DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, tc.dtTimeIn), 0) = t._date
AND     (t.dtTimeIn = tc.dtTimeIn OR t.dtTimeOut = tc.dtTimeOut)
WHERE   e.sDept IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Comment: I assume Date is not a 2005 SQL function?

Comment: @Shmewnix You can try the query now, I adjusted it for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: This is actually very close.  I changed a few things, but for some reason it's grabbing the second punch in by the second person.  So it shows 2 people in the department coming in at 7:30.  Which is normal, it then shows the second person punching in at 11:03 as well...  It should only show the punch in at 7:30 any idea?

Comment: It's showing:

'2/12/2013 7:30:00 AM Fred
2/12/2013 7:30:00 AM Timothy
2/12/2013 11:34:00 AM Timothy'

Comment: You're answer is close enough.  It's got me where I needed to be.  I can't believe I didn't try the MIN or MAX function before... I got too carried away with ranking.  THANKS!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. I wrote it to show the person (or persons if more of them arrived at the same time) who came in earliest and went out latest. If you only want those who came in earliest change the condition `AND     (t.dtTimeIn = tc.dtTimeIn OR t.dtTimeOut = tc.dtTimeOut)` to `AND     t.dtTimeIn = tc.dtTimeIn`, in such case you can also remove `, MAX(tc.dtTimeOut) dtTimeOut` from the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace it with a correlated subquery.  Here is an example for `rk1`:

```
(select count(distinct lEmployeeId)
 from TimeClock tc
 where tc.lEmployeeId = timeclock.lemployeeId and
       tc.dtTimeIn <= timeclock.dtTimeIn
) as rk1
```

Rank can produce multiple records all labelled with 1 (when there are ties).  If you really mean `row_number()`, then you would use `count(*)` in the above query instead of `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 1):

your query just return who closed a location...

to return who open and who closed you need to change your where clause to

```
where rk2 = 1 or rk1 = 1
```

and if you will get from many sDept at same time the order should be partitioned for sDept like this

```
RANK() OVER ( partition by sDept ORDER BY dtTimeIn) rk1, --earliest record gets 1
           RANK() OVER ( partition by sDept ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC) rk2 --latest record get
```

see...

setting an ambient to run your query

```
    declare @TimeClock table ( lEmployeeID int, dtTimeIn datetime, dtTimeOut datetime)
    declare @Employees table ( lEmployeeID int, sfirstname varchar(max),sDept varchar(max))
    declare @getDate date
    set @getDate ='02/12/2013' 

    insert @Employees 
    values (1,'Ana','1')
    ,(2,'Pedro','1')
    ,(3,'Alfred','2')

    insert @TimeClock
    values (1 ,'02/12/2013 08:30','02/11/2013 11:30')
    ,(2 ,'02/12/2013 08:00','02/11/2013 11:00')
    ,(3 ,'02/12/2013 08:15','02/11/2013 11:15')
```

your query...

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT timeclock.dtTimeIn, timeclock.dtTimeOut, employees.sfirstname,
           RANK() OVER (partition by sDept  ORDER BY dtTimeIn) rk1, --earliest record gets 1
           RANK() OVER (partition by sDept  ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC) rk2 --latest record gets 1

        FROM   @TimeClock timeclock
        INNER JOIN @Employees Employees
        ON TimeClock.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID
        WHERE (dtTimeIn > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @getDate)-1, 0)) AND (dtTimeOut < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @getDate), 0)) AND 
          (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
    ) A
    WHERE rk2=1
```

returns...

```
    dtTimeIn            dtTimeOut                   sfirstname  rk1 rk2
    2013-02-12 08:30:00.000 2013-02-11 11:30:00.000 Ana         3   1
```

see.. just who closed is in resultset

changing the where clause...

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT timeclock.dtTimeIn, timeclock.dtTimeOut, employees.sfirstname,
           RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY dtTimeIn) rk1, --earliest record gets 1
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC) rk2 --latest record gets 1

        FROM   @TimeClock timeclock
        INNER JOIN @Employees Employees
        ON TimeClock.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID
        WHERE (dtTimeIn > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @getDate)-1, 0)) AND (dtTimeOut < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @getDate), 0)) AND 
          (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
    ) A
    WHERE rk2=1 
    or rk1 = 1
```

return both.. who open and who closed...

```
        dtTimeIn            dtTimeOut               sfirstname  rk1 rk2
    2013-02-12 08:30:00.000 2013-02-11 11:30:00.000 Ana     3   1

    2013-02-12 08:00:00.000 2013-02-11 11:00:00.000 Pedro   1   3
2013-02-12 08:15:00.000 2013-02-11 11:15:00.000 Alfred  1   1
```

Pedro did opened and Ana closed the sDept '1' and Alfred did opened and closed sDept '2'

Comment: You're correct.  I didn't post the second query.  The question is, how can I accomplish this without using "OVER" so I can use report.