# How to select a subset of rows from a table adapter in the .Net framework

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I know that tableadapter does not support the OVER SQL command as in the following SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dbo.alerts.id) NUM,
   * FROM dbo.Alerts
) A
WHERE NUM > @StartRow AND NUM < @EndRow
```

how would you make the equivalent statement so that the dataset designer will support such queries

Basicly I want to be able to select a subset of rows to present to the UI without loading the whole dataset. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way, any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138725/dataset-tableadapter-throwing-over-sql-construct-or-statement-not-supported

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the direction you want to take, but you could put that sql statement in a stored procedure and use the sproc's parameters to filter the desired subset and then have that get loaded into the dataset.

Doing something like the following:

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(.........);
sqlCommand.CommandText = "theStoredProcedureNameHere";
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter paramWhatever1 = new SqlParameter(......);
SqlParameter paramWhatever2 = new SqlParameter(......);

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramWhatever1);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramWhatever2);

SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sqlAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: lol, +1 for elucidating the answer, anyone hitting the page would get a ready reference of how to implement!

Comment: I will give it a try in a min - ta

Answer (score 0):

Put your query in a stored procedure instead and call it to fill your dataset